# How can I "fill in" a convex hull with points in PCL (C++)

Tags: point-cloud-library, convex-hull, pcl

I have a pointcloud of a plane (which I extracted using RANSAC).
But it has some holes here and there and also the edges aren't so smooth.
So I thought maybe I could first get a Convex hull of the pointcloud and then somehow fill in the convex hull with points to get a perfectly filled plane.

I made the convex hull like this and checked that it works well.

```
chull.setInputCloud(in_cloud);
chull.setDimension(2);
chull.reconstruct(*out_cloud);
```

The hull is in the shape I want it to be and it would be perfect if the inside were just filled in with points.

Does anyone know how I would be able to do it?

In case this isn't possible (or is very inefficient) here are the ways I thought of that could lead to my wanted results

1. (This is the way I wrote about above.) Find the convex hull of a plane, fill the inside of it with points.
2. Create a plane of points using the coefficients of the plane I got through RANSAC. Cropout the points that are inside the convex hull using the CropHull function.
3. Forget about Convex hulls, and just find a way to fill in holes in the original pointcloud of the plane.

Any related help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!